# Applet jar signed with a code signing certificate gives "Digital signature could not be verified error."

Tags: jar, signing

1. I have purchased a code signing certificate. I tried signing an exe with it, and that works fine (meaning Publisher is seen correctly and no error is seen when the exe is executed)
2. I tried to sign an applet jar using the same certificate as follows:

   a. Created a keystore

   b. Imported the certificate in the keystore.

   c. Signed the jar using that keystore

   d. Verified the jar using command :

`jarsigner -verbose -certs -verify -keystore <key_store_name> abc.jar`

Above command execution shows that the jar is verified successfully:

jar verified.
Warning:
This jar contains entries whose signer certificate will expire within six months.

3.When the webpage is accessed, the applet loads, , Publisher is seen correctly, but it still shows the error "The Applications Digital Signature could not be verified. Do you want to run this application?"

Could any one please provide pointers as what could be going wrong?

Comment: It should be possible to get more details about this error from the error dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses a different keystore from the operating system's keystore (at least on Linux, I don't know about other platforms). So it's *possible* that the root CA for the signing chain for your certificate, is not registered with the Java keystore in the version of Java that you have installed, unfortunately.

If this is the case, it would probably make your certificate pretty useless for public applet deployments, but it would be fine if you could ask all users to install the root CA into their Java keystores first (or provide a utility to do so).

Answer (score 0):

My issue got resolved. There was a problem in the certificate (in .pfx format) that I was using to sign the jar. When this certificate was generated from the site of the CA, the checkbox of "Include All Certificates in the path", was not selected. As a result the certificate did not have the complete chain required for signature verification in the applet jar.

The following command can be used to display the details of the certificates in a .pfx file openssl pkcs12 -in .pfx -nodes

The certificate that had an issue, had only 1 certificate listed; while the one generated later had the complete chain of 3 certificates.